# Can derived class member functions return different types than the base class?

Tags: c++, templates, generics, derived-class

I am running into a design issue with my code and I am not sure where to go. I am attempting to write a basic I/O class to write vectors of data into a text file for convenience in my research. In practice, I would like to not worry about the datatype in the array that I am writing to file and use the same interface regardless of if it is an array of `ints`, `doubles`, etc.

My basic idea was to create an `AbstractColumn` class, with a templated derived class to handle columns of different data. My I/O class could then contain an array of pointers to objects of this Abstract Class, and I can can add to this array as needed. See my header file below for the implementation of this.

```
#ifndef BASICIO_H
#define BASICIO_H

#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct AbstractColumn{
    virtual ~AbstractColumn() = 0;
    template <class T> T* get_data(); // Issue comes in here, I think
    int nrows=0;
};

template <class T>
class Column : public AbstractColumn {
    public:
        Column(std::vector<T>& v);
        ~Column();
        T* get_data() {return data;}
        T* data;
        int nrows;
};

template <class T>
Column<T>::Column(std::vector<T>& v){
    nrows = v.size();
    data = static_cast<T*>(malloc(sizeof(T)*v.size())); //malloc returns void* so we need the static cast
    std::memcpy(data, v.data(), v.size());
}

template <class T>
Column<T>::~Column() {}

class BasicIO {
    public:
        BasicIO(std::string outname) : fname(outname), ncols(0) {}
        ~BasicIO();

        template <class T>
        void attach(std::vector<T>& v, std::string name="");
        void write();
        inline int get_ncols() {return ncols;}
        inline std::string filename() {return fname;}
    private:
        std::vector<AbstractColumn*> columns;
        std::vector<std::string> column_names;
        std::string fname;
        int ncols;
};

template <class T>
void BasicIO::attach(std::vector<T>& v, std::string name){
    Column<T>* col = new Column(v);
    columns.push_back(col);
    column_names.push_back(name);
}

#endif
```

My issue is coming in in trying to write the `write()` method that actually dumps this data to a file.

```
void BasicIO::write(){
// other formatting code here
    for(int i = 0; i<columns.at(0)->nrows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<ncols; j++){              
            outfile<<std::scientific<<std::left<<std::setw(col_width)<<(columns.at(j)->get_data())[i]<<" ";
        }                                                              //^ this is causing an error
        outfile<<std::endl;
    }
    outfile.close();
}
```

When I try to compile, I get the an error saying `note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed` and `couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'`. Now, I think I understand what the issue is. When the compiler reaches this point, all it doesn't know what type of data is going to be returned by my `get_data()` function, since in the base class the return type is the template `T`. However, I don't see a way around this and I am very stuck. I have done a bit of reading and it seems like type erasure might be the way to go, but I also think I might be missing something simpler.

**My Question**
All of the above context aside, my concrete question is as follows: What is the best way to have an array which holds objects (in this case columns) of generic types, specifically for the application described above? I am happy to offer any other details as needed, I just felt that my code snippets were already quite long. Thank you for reading.

Comment: `AbstractColumn::get_data()` is not `virtual`, so `Column` can't override it.  And a `virtual` method can't be templated. So you need to re-think your design.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, this I think is the issue. I had tried making it virtual before and exactly as you say that did not work. As for rethinking my design, I would be surprised if this situation is uncommon enough that there aren't some known ways of dealing with it. Any chance you might be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: I would expose a virtual `write()` method in `AbstractColumn` and have `Column` override that. Don't have `BasicIO` poll each column for the actual data to write, let each column write its own data directly to the `outfile` as needed (or, at least, expose additional methods in `BasicIO` for writing basic types, and then each column can call those methods as needed).

Comment: Ah! Wonderful idea, I had not thought to let the derived classes do the writing. Sometimes you get so caught up in a design idea for something that it is hard to imagine a different way of doing it. I will try this, thank you very much for the help. If you want to summarize these suggestions as an answer, I would accept that.

Comment: Just an Idea/Suggestion, if your final objective is to transform data into text and store it. Maybe it's a good option to implement the `>>` operator. 

This will allow you to easilly convert any class to "text". 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-input-operator-for-your-own-classes?view=msvc-170

This also can be implemented with string streams

Comment: `Column<T>::Column(std::vector<T>& v)` looks like a premature optimization. also you're using `malloc`/`memcpy` which should be avoided in C++ code, if possible. Note that you don't free the allocated memory. Furthermore consider the case where the type stored actually owns resources required for printing to work such as `std::string`: You may have copied the pointer to the backing buffer, but if the original vector gets destroyed any access to such a pointer results in undefined behaviour. Copying or moving the vector into a member of `Column<T>` is probably preferrable...